# Проверка пароля, assembler

Tags: строки, ассемблер, tasm

Разбираюсь с ассемблером, столкнулся с такой задачей - необходимо написать программу, которая запрашивает ввод пароля и сравнивает его с заданным. Написал этот почему-то неработающий код, который, как мне кажется, близок к правильному решению. 
В начале два макроса на вывод сообщения и переход на новую строку.Буфер и пароль задаю в конце программы:

```
password DB '5250',0Dh  
input db 16,0,16 dup ('?')
```

При запуске, независимо от введенного пароля, выводит сообщение "WRONG PASSWORD" - то есть заданный пароль и введенная строка не совпадают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка в моем коде?

```
code_seg segment
ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG,DS:code_seg,ES:code_seg    

org 100h  


print_mes macro message   ; print message
  local msg, nxt
  push AX
  push DX

  mov AH,09h
  mov DX, offset msg
  int 21h

  pop DX
  pop AX
  jmp nxt
  msg DB 13,10, message,'$'
  nxt:
endm   

next_line macro    ; emulate enter
  push AX
  push DX

  mov AH, 02h

  mov DL, 13
  int 21h
  mov DL, 10
  int 21h

  pop DX
  pop AX
endm
;--------------------------------------------------------------------

start:
 print_mes 'INPUT PASSWORD>' 

  mov ah,0Ah               
  mov dx,offset input   
  int 21h  

  next_line  
  cld
  mov cx,5
  mov si,offset password
  mov di,offset input
  repe cmpsb            
  je equal

  not_equal:
  print_mes 'WRONG PASSWORD!'
  int 20h
  jmp exit

  equal:
  print_mes 'DONE!' 
  int 20h  
  jmp exit  


int 20h
exit:

password DB '5250',0Dh  
input db 16,0,16 dup ('?')  

code_seg ends 
end start
```

Comment: посмотрите что возвращает в буфере функция 9h. там максимальная длина и в следующем байте актуальная и только после этого идет строка. http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0018.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение задачи:**
Добавил сравнение длины заданного пароля с длиной введенной строки; немного изменил структуру программы; ввел переменную-флаг Access (1==пароль введен верно); изменил объявление буфера.

```
code_seg segment
ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG,DS:code_seg,ES:code_seg    

org 100h  


print_mes macro message   ; print message
  local msg, nxt
  push AX
  push DX

  mov AH,09h
  mov DX, offset msg
  int 21h

  pop DX
  pop AX
  jmp nxt
  msg DB message,'$'
  nxt:
endm   

next_line macro    ; emulate enter
  push AX
  push DX

  mov AH, 02h

  mov DL, 13
  int 21h
  mov DL, 10
  int 21h

  pop DX
  pop AX
endm
;--------------------------------------------------------------------

start:

print_mes 'INPUT PASSWORD>'
mov ah ,0Ah             
mov dx,offset MaxInputLen
int 21h             
mov dl,10
mov ah,6
int 21h
next_line
;------------------------------------------------------------------

mov ah,passLen  
mov bh,InputLen 
cmp ah,bh           
jne wrong       
mov di,offset pass  
mov si,offset InputBuff 
mov cx,PassLen      
cld         
repe cmpsb      
jne wrong           
mov Access,1    
wrong:          

cmp Access,1
je done
print_mes 'WRONG PASSWORD'
int 20h
jmp exit 

done:
print_mes 'DONE!'
int 20h
jmp exit


exit:
pass db '5250'                  
passLen=$-pass                      
MaxInputLen db 50               
InputLen db 0                       
InputBuff db 50 dup (0)                 
Access db 0         

code_seg ends 
end start
```